# How to get a heap object (tree) in python?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-heap

I don't understand python's heapq module. You can push and pop, but it doesn't
return an actual heap object ... So I ask myself, does it recreate the tree every single time
I push on it? Why is it not giving a heap object? Do you know an alternative to heapq?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found that you can do this with: queue.PriorityQueue
A bit counter intuitive naming, when you search for heap...

Comment: No, that isn't how you use `heapq`